# Selector background does not work?

Tags: android, selector

Use Selector as view's background, like following codes :

my_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/cell_bg_e" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/cell_bg_e" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/cell_bg_e" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/cell_bg_n_trans" />
</selector>
```

MyView.java

```
    public class MyView extends LinearLayout
{
    public MyView(Context context, CharSequence text, Drawable drawable) {
        super(context);
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_selector);
    }
}
```

it works on all the devices except for some certain 800x480 resolution device(lick htc g12)

why ?

Comment: isnt the view is clickable?

Comment: yes, it is clickable. click on it will lead to some action like start activity

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure the view you have set this selector drawable as a background of is clickable.

You can do this in code:

```
public MyView(Context context, CharSequence text, Drawable drawable) {
    super(context);
    setClickable(true);
    setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_selector);
}
```

Alternatively in XML:

```
<MyView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/my_selector"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"/>
```